# How to handle cross language questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Since the release of [Apple's new language](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) there has been a flood of questions based on [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language). I've also seen a few questions that would have been precariously similar to others if they were written in Objective-C.

Here are a few examples

[Swift: ViewController Error in webView project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026697/swift-viewcontroller-error-in-webview-project)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024313/uiswitch-read-value-with-swift

[How to Set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and dequeueReusableCell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062285/how-to-set-uitableview-style-and-dequeuereusablecell-in-swift#24062285)

[CLLocation Manager in Swift to get Location of User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063798/cllocation-manager-in-swift-to-get-location-of-user)

[Creating NSData from NSString in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039868/creating-nsdata-from-nsstring-in-swift)

[Downloading and parsing json in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift)

[How to create UILabel programmatically by Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081731/how-to-create-uilable-programmatically-by-swift-language)

[How to get device width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084941/xcode-6-swift-how-can-get-device-width-and-height)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146897/uitableviewcells-and-uitableviews-in-swift

This list has been growing over the last few days.

---

As more people start using this language these questions will become more common. Given the similarities between the languages and the nearly congruent APIs should cross-language questions be marked as duplicates?

Perhaps they should even be closed because of lack of research. Some questions can very easily be *translated* from Objective-C based questions to Swift with a little research into the language.

My worry is that allowing Swift questions with very similar existing Objective-C answers will encourage help-vampires who don't want to take the effort to research the problem themselves.

Comment: One suspects that SO will be Swiftly inundated with this nonsense.  And a lot of the questions appear to be from folks who don't know elementary Java or C.  Eg, one asked "What does `+=` mean?"

Comment: @Hot Or rep whores, thrilled to have finally found something to ask about that will not be a duplicate. Depending on how cynical you are. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray so should they be marked as duplicates?

Comment: The answer is, as always: 42 ;-) Well, actually it depends, do what makes sense.

Comment: Calm them down until they are no longer cross.

Comment: @bmargulies - I thought it was the language that was cross.  (I'd be cross too if I were abused as much as Swift is by these know-nothings.)

Answer (score 4):

Swift is just another language that can be used to program the Cocoa family of frameworks (along with Objective-C, Python, AppleScript, C#, etc.).

At the risk of over-generalising, here: A quick glance at the tag tells me that most questions on Swift currently are asked by people having difficulties distinguishing between a programming language, a development framework, a platform and a couple of other abstractions that we delight our brainy selves with.

Not incidentally, the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag suffers from exactly the same problem.

If you really want to help these people, then you should help them understand how the language is different from the framework, and how to use the first to get to the second.

If you don't think you have time for this (it would effectively amount to providing one-to-one tutoring sessions in object-oriented programming) then I would suggest that you just add [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) to your ignore-list on the front page. You can't save them all.

Comment: and please retag (i.e. remove the Xcode tag) correctly if possible.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Yes - but... the Xcode tag carries implicit and invaluable meta-information. I wrote [a piece](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178510/174374) about the taxonomy of the Apple-related tags, which I believe still holds true.

Comment: I lol'd and then I cried

Comment: Maybe `xcode` should be changed to `xcode-ide` or some such.